# simple SNTP python script

Tags: python

I need help to complete following script:

```py
import socket
import struct
import sys
import time

NTP_SERVER = '0.uk.pool.ntp.org'
TIME1970 = 2208988800L

def sntp_client():
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    data = str.encode('\xlb' + 47 * '\0')
    client.sendto(data, (NTP_SERVER, 123))
    data, addr = client.recvfrom(1024)
    if data:
        print('Response received from:', addr)
    t = struct.unpack('!12I', data)[10]
    t -= TIME1970
    print('\tTime: %s' % time.ctime(t))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sntp_client()
```

Expected output:

```py
Response received from: ('80.82.244.120', 123)
      Time: Tue Sep 13 14:49:38 2016
```

Problem is that program is not giving any output. It looks like it stucks at:

```py
data, addr = client.recvfrom(1024)
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: your program is waiting for a response from server but the server is not responding so it is waiting for ever. are you sure you are sending the proper data? or the server is up and running? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @AminEtesamian Actually, I am referring a book named '**Python Network Programming Cookbook**'. Above program is one of the example from the book.

Comment: the server might be down or not working anymore. you could run your own server for testing and working purposes.

Comment: @AminEtesamian I'll try and see if it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the working script from the **Second Edition** of **[Python Network Programming Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/python-network-programming-cookbook-second-edition)**:

```
import socket, struct, sys, time

NTP_SERVER = '0.uk.pool.ntp.org'
TIME1970 = 2208988800

def sntp_client():
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    data = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'
    client.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), (NTP_SERVER, 123))
    data, address = client.recvfrom(1024)
    if data: print('Response received from:', address)
    t = struct.unpack('!12I', data)[10] - TIME1970
    print('\tTime = %s' % time.ctime(t))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sntp_client()
```

Comment: Works. This is why i love so.

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48473935/10197418) neglects the fraction part of the timestamp, see e.g. [IETF RFC5905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905), p.13. A code snippet including it could look like

```py
import socket
import struct
import datetime

NTP_SERVER = '0.uk.pool.ntp.org'
NTP_DELTA = 2208988800 # given as system epoch (e.g. 1970-1-1) minus NTP epoch (1900-1-1) in [s]

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as client:
    data = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'
    client.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), (NTP_SERVER, 123))
    data, _ = client.recvfrom(256)
    tx_s, tx_f = struct.unpack('!12I', data)[10:12] # seconds and fractional seconds
    tx_timestamp = (tx_s + float(tx_f)/2**32) - NTP_DELTA
    
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(tx_timestamp, datetime.timezone.utc)) 
# e.g.
# 2019-12-18 13:02:14.029521+00:00 # Note: UTC used here for output!
```

Also keep in mind that this only returns the transmit timestamp (tx; time when the server sent the packet). If you look for the milliseconds, the round trip delay might be signficant (see e.g. p.29 of the linked RFC5905).

Sidenote: the [socket docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/socket.html) recommend to open the socket in a `with` context so that it is closed properly when not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your script as written, you need to look for another reason why the server might not be responding to you, such as firewall settings.
My own python SNTP script is almost exactly the same:

```py
    #!/bin/env python

    import socket
    import struct
    import sys
    import time

    TIME1970 = 2208988800L      # Thanks to F.Lundh

    pow2_31 = pow(2,31)
    pow2_32 = pow(2,32)
    pow2_16 = pow(2,16)

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.stderr.write("Usage : " + sys.argv[0] + " <SNTP server>")
        exit(1)

    server = sys.argv[1]

    client = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
    data = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'
    time_start = time.time()
    try:
        client.sendto( data, ( server, 123 ))
        client.settimeout(2)
    except:
        print "server <%s> not recognized" % (server)
        exit(2)
    try:
        data, address = client.recvfrom( 1024 )
    except socket.timeout:
        print "timed out"
        exit(3)

    if data:
        time_reply = (time.time() - time_start) * 1000
        print 'received %d bytes  from %s in %d ms :' % (len(data), address, time_reply)
        upacket = struct.unpack( '!48B', data )
        print upacket
```

usage:

```
$ ./sntp_client.py 0.uk.pool.ntp.org
```

```
received 48 bytes  from ('83.170.75.28', 123) in 154 ms :
(28, 3, 3, 236, 0, 0, 1, 171, 0, 0, 3, 0, 20, 139, 208, 232, 219, 177, 86, 148, 230, 192, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 219, 177, 88, 27, 60, 214, 85, 212, 219, 177, 88, 27, 60, 238, 157, 39)
```